# Azure java functions post method , sending form-data

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, serverless

I followed this tutorial here 
[functions-create-first-java-maven](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-java-maven)

Except, what I am trying to do is just have a post method, and pass form-data in request body.

here is my function code

```
@FunctionName("create-request")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = { HttpMethod.POST }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) final HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");
        context.getLogger().info("RequestBody:- " + request.getBody());
        final int keyIndex = request.getBody().toString().indexOf("request");
        if (keyIndex != -1) {
            final String restString = request.getBody().toString().substring(keyIndex);

            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello, " + restString).build();

        }
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body").build();
    }
```

I try with postman
[image]

nothing in response , but my local console shows a whole lot of exceptions ,

This seems to be the main problem here.

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HLH77AHEFKOM", Request id "0HLH77AHEFKOM:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.create-request ---> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Rpc.RpcException: Result: Failure
Exception: Cannot locate the method signature with the given input
Stack: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Cannot locate the method signature with the given input
        at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodExecutor.lambda$execute$0(JavaMethodExecutor.java:49)
        at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
        at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodExecutor.execute(JavaMethodExecutor.java:49)
        at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:47)
        at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)
        at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
        at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)
        at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

But , interesting thing is , when I pass the same data as x-www-form-urlencoded, it works just fine.

So, I would like to know if do I need to modify the @HttpTrigger params and pass some other configuration to specify that the function should support , form-data as well as urlencoded way ? Since, I would prefer to pass data as form-data and not as urlencoded.
Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `form-data` content type is not supported currently by Httptrigger function.

My workaround is that we could add our logic to handle it.

We could get the content-type from the request header then handle the value by ourselves

The following is the demo code.

```
Map<String,String> headers = request.getHeaders();
if(headers.get("content-type").contains("multipart/form-data"))
{
    //add logic to handle the value
}
else if(headers.get("content-type").contains("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
{
     //add logic to handle the value       
}
```

Comment: Let me try this, and i will get back to you. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: Even with your suggested way, as soon as I hit a request with request header being key as `content-type` and value as `multipart/form-data`, it just throws the same error. Works fine for form-urlencoded option.

Comment: How to declare the `MultipartHttpServletRequest` variable? There's no `HttpServerletRequest` in the paramters of `HttpResponseMessage.run()` method. There is only `HttpRequestMessage request` and it cannot be converted to `HttpServerletRequest`. You know to fetch a file from the multipart/form request, 'HttpServerletRequest' is needed.